# How do I make an operator be evaluated before methods?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

If I define an operator,

```
class Object
  def ~@
    self || ErrorlessNil.new
  end
end
```

how can I make it so that the `~` is evaluated first, instead of last? Right now, something like

```
~[1][100].undefined_method
```

will throw an error, while

```
(~[0][22]).randomsadfldsf
```

works fine. The goal is to define a tool that works like coffeescript's question mark. I could make a `??` method but I can't start with a `?`, and `_?` works ok, but that is not fun.

Comment: What’s `NewNil`? Does it have a `method_missing` that’s responding to `randomsadfldsf` in your second example?

Comment: BTW: Your method is equivalent to `self || NewNil.new`

Comment: Question is not clear. The method name `undefined_method` seems to imply that it is not defined. If that is the case, of course it raises an error. What is the point of that example?

Comment: ohh, good catch, thank you! the real one looks like this (after i removed the ternary): self || @new_nil ||= NewNil.new because  I would like my NewNil to only exist once (be a singleton or what have  you). And yeah, NewNill has a method_missing so it can not throw errors and just return nil (or, NewNil, or other stuff depending on args)

Comment: @sawa, the question is just how to make operators evaluate first. in this example the operator makes it return a class that does not through errors on undefined methods, but the question is independant of that, though first answer says this is impossible, which is a bummer

Comment: You can define non-standard methods but you should use `define_method`:  `class A; define_method '?' do; puts '?'; end; end;` and you use `send` instead of `obj.meth`: `A.new.send '?'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

In Ruby, you can only override the behavior of existing operators. You cannot define new operators nor can you change their precedence, arity, associativity or fixity.

This is unlike, for example, Haskell or Fortress, which allow you to define your own operators with your own fixity (prefix, postfix, infix), associativity (left, right, none) and precedence. Ruby is like Python, C# and C++ in this regard.

Comment: So, just to steal more of your time away, how would you recommend solving this problem (besides switching languages)? Just using a regular post-fixed-dotted method that checks to return the ErrorlessNil class?

Comment: @user2251284 Your question is also unclear in the sense that, if `~` had stronger precedence than other method application, then `~[0][22].randomsadfldsf` would not be interpreted as `(~[0][22]).randomsadfldsf` but as `(~[0])[22].randomsadfldsf`.

Answer (score 3):

Jörg W Mittag's answer provides one reason it will not work like you want, but there is another reason.

If `~` had stronger precedence than other method application, then

```
~[0][22].randomsadfldsf
```

would not be interpreted as

```
(~[0][22]).randomsadfldsf
```

but as

```
(~[0])[22].randomsadfldsf
```

Comment: ooooohh, that is an excellent point! In that case, though I wont think about it too much since its impossible to get there it seems, maybe I would have to figure out a way to make ~ define a method_missing on what it touches (so Arrays would return ErrorlessNil on a bad look up, for example). though that would not be contagious to later calls, but thats how, in effect, it is in coffeescript i believe.

Answer (score 1):

Obvious and easy answer is that, aside `()`, you cannot change operator precedence.

However you REALLY want, you can use `eval`* or/and you can build your Abstract syntax tree (AST)/SEXP.

```
str = "~[1,2,3].first"
def foo str
  if str[0] == '~'
    obj, meth = str[1..-1].split '.'
    eval "(~#{obj}).#{meth}"
  end
end
foo str
```

`foo` require that `str` is in this format:

```
"<~><object/literal without dot><method without dot>"
```

With more complex code, `foo` becomes more complex. You will end with some [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Regexp.html) or with AST/SEXP.

[Build-in Ruby Ripper](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html) can change source into sexp. There is gem named [Sorcerer](https://github.com/jimweirich/sorcerer). It can change Sexp from the Ripper back to source. However it was tested with 1.9.3 and 2.0 only.

*eval may be insecure because it may run code that you don't want to. Check you string before evaling it!